# Adding users list in Tenant.cs

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have started working on with the boilerplate template using Angular, .NET Framework and Module Zero.

I am using multi-tenancy and I'm trying to modify the Tenants view so that it lists users in every tenant so I tried adding `public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }` to the Tenant class and `public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }` to the User class.

After migration and updating the database everything looks good in db. In GetTenants() the tenantManager returns tenants with the Users list being null and  the same goes to users getting null as Tenant from userManager.

Is there any build in way or best practices doing this with boilerplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using EntityFrameworkCore, you have to use eager-loading.

```
// TenantManager.cs
var tenants = TenantRepository.GetAllIncluding(t => t.Users);

// UserManager.cs
var users = AbpStore.UserRepository.GetAllIncluding(u => u.Tenant);
```

Remember to configure inverse property:

```
[InverseProperty("Tenant")]
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
```

You need to disable `IMayHaveTenant` filter to view cross-tenant entities:

```
using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
{
    var tenants = TenantRepository.GetAllIncluding(t => t.Users);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Also when adding users list to Tenant class and tenant to User class migration for some reason adds TenantId as foreign key and adds column Tenant_Id for AbpUsers and adds it as foreign key also

Comment: Migration adds Tenant_Id in [AbpTenants] table  
`public override void Up() { AddColumn("dbo.AbpUsers", "Tenant_Id", c => c.Int()); CreateIndex("dbo.AbpUsers", "TenantId");  
 CreateIndex("dbo.AbpUsers", "Tenant_Id");  
 AddForeignKey("dbo.AbpUsers", "Tenant_Id", "dbo.AbpTenants", "Id");  
 AddForeignKey("dbo.AbpUsers", "TenantId", "dbo.AbpTenants", "Id"); }`

Comment: I couldn't get the users list working with your answer even aftet solving the db migration issue(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338234/database-migration-adds-new-column-tenancy-id-when-adding-tenant-to-user-class)

Comment: I tried this with fresh template and only added the changes in classes you saw in the db migration post(thanks for the answer btw) and in TenantAppService I have tried the following:

`public ListResultDto<TenantDto> GetTenants()
{
        var users_test = _tenantManager.Tenants.ToList();
        var users_test1 = _tenantRepository.GetAllIncluding(t => t.Users);
        var users_test2 = _tenantRepository.GetAllList();
        var users_test3 = _tenantManager.GetById(1);
        return _tenantManager.Tenants                  
         ); 
}`

Comment: Debugging still gives me Users Count=0 in users_test1. I have two users, admin and testuser, in db with TenantId=1("Default" tenancy)

Comment: I ran the seed first and after that migration

Comment: All users have the right `TenantId` . Migration has `CreateIndex("dbo.AbpUsers", "TenantId");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.AbpUsers", "TenantId", "dbo.AbpTenants", "Id");`  And in db `AbpUsers` has foreign key `FK_dbo.AbpUsers_dbo.AbpTenants_TenantId`

Comment: Nope. I can't figure out the problem. Is there any way you could check my project for me? There isn't much addition to what I have presented here though

Comment: Yes I have inverse property in Tenant class

Comment: I was logged in as Host and trying to view all users in all tenants. Adding `MayHaveTenant` did the trick. Thanks!